# How not to get SettingWithCopyWarning when setting a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an annoying problem with SettingWithCopyWarning and I don't seem to get rid of the warning. I have a df users like this

```
user id     cloud_files 
    1              0
    2              8
    3              1
```

I would like to add a boolean column of cloud users

```
user id     cloud_files     cloud_user  
    1              0           false
    2              8           true  
    3              1           true
```

I have tried to do it but I keep getting the SettingWithCopyWarning.

```
users['cloud_user'] = np.where(users['cloud_files']== 0, True, False)
```

```
users['cloud_user'] = users['cloud_files']!= 0
```

```
users.loc[:,'cloud_user'] = users['cloud_files']!= 0
```

I have tried copy and reset index but I just can't get rid of the warning. Is there some way to do it without getting this warning or do I just need to set the warning off?

Comment: @BrendanA That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use properties of booleans to directly create your new column because `bool(num)` will evaluate to `True` as long the num is non-zero

```
df['cloud_user'] = df['cloud_files'].astype(bool)
```

Result:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,2,3],'cloud_files':[0,8,1]})
>>> df['cloud_user'] = df['cloud_files'].astype(bool)
>>> df
   user_id  cloud_files  cloud_user
0        1            0       False
1        2            8        True
2        3            1        True
```

Comment: This as as well gives me the SettingWithCopyWarning.

Comment: @Ruvuki how is your `df` constructed? is your `df` the original dataframe, or is it a view of another dataframe? if you run just my two lines of code, you shouldn't get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: The df was really the problem. When I took a copy of it and worked with that I had no problems with adding the column.